# Unable to process loop faster

Tags: c#, performance, linq, optimization

I have this specific code:

```cs
public static string To_Bits(string data, object ConversionTable)
{
    string toBits = "";
    string tmpBin = "";
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ConversionTable);
    var cTable = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);

    for (int i=0; i<data.Count(); i++)
    {
        tmpBin = data[i].ToString();
        toBits += cTable[tmpBin];
        
    }

    return toBits;
}
```

As the data gets larger, the conversion based on the `conversionTable` takes longer, and in some instances VS 2019 gives me the following message "The application is in break mode".

Is their a way to optimize this code to have it process faster, via LINQ or another method?

Comment: Well for starters, serializing to and then deserializing from JSON, while a practical trick for deep-cloning objects, is far less efficient than cloning an object using code specifically dedicated to that task, with no intermediary requiring strings. Then there's the exceedingly peculiar operation of breaking a string down to characters, but turning each of these into a string, rather than using the character directly. It may be worth taking a step back and seeing if this entire table is even a good idea to begin with (as in, what is the high-level operation you're doing)?

Comment: Can you provide an example for `data` and `ConversionTable` too? 
there are two problems here: first, you should not serialize and deserialize to JSON, second problem is string concatenation that you should use StringBuilder instead.

Comment: What is `ConversionTable`? It seems very odd that you serialise & deserialise it. Given your usage it seems it should really be a `Dictionary<char, char>` or `Dictionary<char, string>` and that the method signature should specify that.

Comment: The conversion table is basically letters assigned to binary values for example: A=0000, B=0001, C=0010,D=0011 etc. The conversion table is a object, so I use serialize and deserialize to convert to to a dictionary. Also sample data may be in the form of AABCDABBC. I use A as the key to retrieve the value of 0000 from the dictionary. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

There are two slow moments:

- `data.Count()` - it is calculating length of string on each loop iteration
- `toBits +=`  better to use `StringBuilder` to avoid unnecessary allocations

```cs
public static string To_Bits(string data, object ConversionTable)
{
    var toBits = new StringBuilder();
    var tmpBin = "";
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ConversionTable);
    var cTable = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);

    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
    {
        tmpBin = data[i].ToString();
        toBits.Append(cTable[tmpBin]);
    }

    return toBits.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try replacing

```
     for (int i=0; i<data.Count(); i++)
     {
       tmpBin = data[i].ToString();
       toBits += cTable[tmpBin];        
     }
```

with

```
     foreach (string c in data)
     {
         toBits += cTable[c];     
      }
```

Comment: That won't compile. `data` is a `string`.

Comment: The conversion table is basically letters assigned to binary values for example: A=0000, B=0001, C=0010,D=0011 etc. The conversion table is a object, so I use serialize and deserialize to convert to to a dictionary. Also sample data may be in the form of AABCDABBC. I use A as the key to retrieve the value of 0000 from the dictionary. Hope this helps.

Comment: In foreach statement change data to data.ToCharArray()